# Characterization of a sphere: every "sub-sphere" has two centers

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, problem-solving

Let me ask this question without too much formalization:

Suppose a smooth surface $M$ has the property that for all spheres $S(p,R)$ (i.e. the set of all points which lie a distance $R\geq 0$ from $p \in M$, with distance as measured inside the surface), there is always a different point $q(p,R) \in M$ and a distance $D(p,R)\geq 0$ so that $$S(p,R)=S(q(p,R),D(p,R))$$
In words: both $p$ and $q(p,R) \neq p$ are a center of the sphere $S(p,R)$.

**Q**: Is $M$ (a part of) a sphere? More formally: is $M$ isometric to (a subset of) a sphere?

Remark: Spheres clearly possess the mentioned property, with every sub-sphere having one point $p$ ánd its antipodal $\pi(p)$ at its center. This property is maintained when we remove a finite number of pairs of antipodal points from such a sphere or when we take a few disconnected spheres.

This question has a [counterpart](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581644/characterization-of-a-sphere-sub-spheres-have-two-antipodal-centers) on stackexchange.

Answer (score 15):

[Blaschke's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiedersehen_pair) might be relevant. In particular, if the surface is $S^2$ with a $C^3$ metric, then it follows from Blaschke's conjecture, [proved by Green.](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=155271) This states that a metric on the sphere in which every point has a unique conjugate point must be the round metric on the 2-sphere. In your condition, one may observe that $q(p,R)$ does not depend on $R$, essentially by the [Gauss lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)) The point is that the sphere of radius $r$ about $B(p,R)$ (the ball of radius $R$ about $p$) is $S(p,r+R)$. Hence $q(p,R)=q(p,r+R)=q(p)$. Then $q(p)$ is the unique point conjugate to $p$.

For the general case, it might follow by taking the completion of the metric, and showing that it must be a (topological) sphere.

Comment: Have you had alook at the answer on the similar question on stackexchange? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581644/characterization-of-a-sphere-sub-spheres-have-two-antipodal-centers

Comment: While your answer certainly seems pleasing to me, I want to take some more time to analyse Lee's answer and see what's of it. May take a few days, unfortunately.